# Already deployed asp.net web application wont run in different machine

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc

I am trying to run an already-deployed ASP.NET web application on a different machine, but I am getting a machine-to-application error. I am a beginner to ASP so please help me out with this.

This is the error which I get:

> "It is an error to use a section registered as allowDefinition='MachineToApplication' beyond application level. This error can be caused by a virtual directory not being configured as an application in IIS."

Comment: you have .NET framework installed on that machine ? an how you hosted the application in different machine ?

Comment: ya i have visual studio 2010 installed on it.with .net framework 4.0.

Comment: so your application also using the .net framework 4.0 ?

Comment: i have to update the already deployed app.the previous deployment was done by my seniors.and now i have been placed to take c are of project rightnow... so i am totally blind to this deployment and all. so if have to modify the source code how i can do it. please help me sir

Comment: yes my application is also using .net framework 4.0

Comment: have you tried anything so far?

Comment: they deployed it using IIS manager 7.0

Comment: nope.....at the first step itself i have been hang.....i cant run it atleast...

Comment: first you need to install the IIS on that machine. did you installed ?

Comment: no...previously it was not installed...so i am insatlling it now...and will do accordingly what MR Mark Fitzpatrick  said below...and later i will get back to u both...

Comment: refer think link it is very useful http://www.asp.net/mvc/overview/deployment/visual-studio-web-deployment/deploying-to-iis

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out that the VS was complaining about a configuration section within the web.config file in the Backup folder application...just remove the backup folder so it doesn't have a web.config file under the Virtual directory that your ASP.NET application is running in.

Hope this will help you,
for more detail go through

http://forums.asp.net/t/1031775.aspx?Configuration+Error+allowDefinition+MachineToApplication+beyond+application+level

Comment: thank you vidhi trivedi...i removed the back up folder in bin folder.theat error got solved

Answer (score 2):

This is an error that is received when you deploy the application to a folder that is not marked as an application in IIS and you have a configuration setting that only works at the root application level. You don't have to do anything with the application, this should completely be an IIS setting. Right-click on the folder in IIS and select Convert to Application and choose the Application Pool appropriate for your application's framework version.

Comment: thank you sir..i just configured the virtual directory in iis manager...and it helped me